# How can I add back server explorer and data sources and toolbox (especially toolbox) to the far left menu, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am having difficulty docking toolbox with server explorer and data sources, in visual studio

If I do window..reset window layout,  I get the toolbox where I want it. The reset position. With server explorer and data sources

[image]

But when I  click toolbox on the far left, and it appears, and I drag it a bit, the toolbox option  disappears from the far left and I can't get it back without doing window..reset

[image]

And I have the same problem with server explorer and data sources.

If I click them and drag the window, I can't the option back, and in fact I completely lose the menu on the far left

[image]

I have tried dragging toolbox around and different places appear for it to rest, but I can't make it go somewhere such that an option appears in the far left again, without having to do window..reset window layout.

To elaborate..

I can drag the toolbox and so that the far left arrow gets highlighted, and then release, but then it  still doesn't appear as text in the far left

[image]

[image]

^^ See in the above pictures I don't get

toolbox appearing

[image]

or to show a fuller view

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag that window to the left or right side you will get the mark where you want to place it. than leave that window your window will be docked there.

[image]

**EDITED:**

Windows should be Dockable and after placing the window at your position you can unpin that window so, it can be collapsed when the mouse leave.

[image]

Comment: can you show an image of how it docks and you get the name of it get to the left hand side? 'cos it doesn't work for me

Comment: i have updated my answer. and make sure you have you have selected Windows Mode as Dockable.

Comment: Thanks, the dragging to the left area, then unpinning(clicking that pin, toggling it) gets the text "toolbar" in the far left. And I can click the toolbox button in the far left and it shows and hides fine.